# PyCharm Console outputs "None" for no apparent reason

Tags: python, class, console, pycharm, string.format

So I was doing a little tutorial on inheritance in Python and created this class:

```
class Animal:
# variables with 2 underscores in front of them are private and can
# only be modified using functions inside the class
__name = ""
__height = 0
__weight = 0
__sound = ""

def __init__(self, name, height, weight, sound):
    self.__name = name
    self.__height = height
    self.__weight = weight
    self.__sound = sound

def setName(self, name):
    self.__name = name

def getName(self):
    return self.__name

def setHeight(self, height):
    self.__height = height

def getHeight(self):
    return self.__height

def setWeight(self, weight):
    self.__weight = weight

def getWeight(self):
    return self.__weight

def setSound(self, sound):
    self.__sound = sound

def getSound(self):
    return self.__sound

def getType(self):
    print("Animal")

def toString(self):
    print("{} is {} cm tall, weighs {} kilogram and says {}".format(self.__name,
                                                                    self.__height,
                                                                    self.__weight,
                                                                    self.__sound))
```

I then created an object:

```
cat = Animal("Charlie", 38, 12, "Meow")
print(cat.toString())
```

But when I run the program, the console tells me:

Charlie is 38 cm tall, weighs 12 kilogram and says Meow
None

I'm trying to figure out why the "None" is there because it seems to be doing everything right, it's inputting all the values I give it. I'm very new to Python, hope someone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your toString() method does not return anything it just prints the string.

When a method does not return anything , by default it's return value is None , and this is the reason when you do 'print(cat.toString())' , you print None , which is the return value of your method .

From the name of the function , seems like you want to return the value from it instead of printing it there . Code -

```
def toString(self):
    return "{} is {} cm tall, weighs {} kilogram and says {}".format(self.__name,
                                                                    self.__height,
                                                                    self.__weight,
                                                                    self.__sound)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

Your `toString` method is printing the sentence and then you're calling a `print` function on it.

You can either change def toString to return the sentence:

```
def toString(self):
    return ("{} is {} cm tall, weighs {} kilogram and says {}".format(self.__name,
                                                                    self.__height,
                                                                    self.__weight,
                                                                    self.__sound))
```

Or you can leave the print out when you invoke the method:

```
cat = Animal("Charlie", 38, 12, "Meow")
cat.toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another case where the None would appear which i found in my work and fixed would be in a mistake of coding like this;

```
input(print("what is your input?"))
```

the output is;

```
what is your input?
None
```

the problem is similar if not the same as above but here specifically your saying the input is a print statement without getting a real input so the machine thinks there is no input so it outputs "None". in the console you can still type after the "none"and it will register it as input but you might as well get rid of it by getting rid of the print statement so...

```
input("what is your input?")
```

output;

```
what is your input?
```